# building nested array or hash to handle roles/permissions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've set up my permissions and roles basically according to this [blog](http://through-voidness.blogspot.com/2013/10/advanced-rails-4-authorization-with.html).  The roles have `activities` and those `activities` are an Array of Strings describing a controller and action.  So, role `user_manager.activities == ["user:index", "user:create"...]`.

Ultimately, I'd like to have a nested array or array of hashes that looks something like

```
["controller"["action", "action", "action"], "controller"["action", "action", "action"]..]
```

or

```
["controller" =>["action", "action", "action"]]
```

This array will eventually be used by `roles.index.html` to display the activities that a given role would have and also it would be used to assign permissions for a role through `roles/create.html.erb`.  I've never set anything like this up before.  I just wanted to pick your brains to see if this is a feasible way to do what I need to or am I off track on this.

Currently, I have the beginnings of the method I'll use, but I'm not quite wrapping my head around how it needs to be implemented.

```
def activity_array
  @activities = []
  for activity in activities
    act = activity.split ":"
    #if act[0] is unique (so I don't end up with the controller names listed for each action
    @activities.push act[0]
    #end
    #something like @activities[0][1].push act[1] done for each iteration
end
```

Comment: Hmm... not to throw you off course, but have you seen this: https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role ? I sounds a lot like what you are trying to do. Unless you are writing your own on purpose, for learning, etc.

Comment: You're right, that is pretty similar to what I'm trying to do.  I am using the pundit gem for authorization, though.  That fact was noted in my original tags, but was removed by an admin.  Maybe, TheRole's source code has something that I can pick out as a solution for what I'm doing.  Thanks!